# Vue.js dist folder when copied to Shared hosting site's subfolder is not rendering and showing a blank page

Tags: https, vuejs3, subdirectory, shared-hosting

After successfully running `npm run build` I copied the contents of the `/dist` folder in my local `wwwroot` folder. Everything renders correctly and I an see my page.

The problem comes when I copy the same contents of the `/dist` folder to a sub-directory on a Shared Hosting site (Domain.com or GoDaddy.com):  https://www.mywebsite.com/sub-directory

All I see is a blank page. Upon checking the Network tab in developer tools, I see all requests status come back with 200 Status Code.

At this point I have thrown the towel and would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

I went around my problem and solved it in another fashion. Instead of making a subfolder in `/public_html` folder, I created a subdomain using the configuration menu. Therefore my site looked like: `https://mysubdomain.myoriginalsite.com`

While creating a subdomain, the shared-hosting site's configuration asks me what should be the folder for this newly requested subdomain.
So I created a folder in the root (same level as `/public_html`) called `/mysubdomain` and copied all my files from `/dist` folder over there.
It worked like a charm.

**Please NOTE:** In vue.config.js file I updated my publicPath variable to be '' instead of '/'